# Changes for bitcoin.conf file and details on the testnet network bitcoin-core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet, bitcoin-core-development, testnet

I have installed bitcoin core testnet and it is now synchronized with the network after 24 hours.

My question is about bitcoin.conf file.

I will tell you the procedure I used to install:

I created the start testnet.bat file with this command :
**start "" bitcoin-qt.exe -regnet -datadir=./data_regnet/ -prune=550**

Now There is this bitcoin.conf file in "data_testnet" folder. But the thing is it is empty.

And as I am new to this so want to know should I make any changes to bitcoin.conf file or leave it as it is.

And another question is right now I haven't closed the wallet in fear of losing the synchronization that it took so long, So the next time when I want to access the wallet I can directly start my **start testnet.bat** file??

Operating System: **Windows 10 (x64-bit)**

Bitcoin-core version: **0.16.3**

Thank you:)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is `regnet`? I think the option you want is `regtest`.

Comment: 0.16 is also almost half a decade old.

Comment: Yeah regtest* typo

Comment: From where I am learning it has 0.16 so...

Answer (score 0):

`bitcoin.conf` is a file where you can define configurations to `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-qt` persistently, you if you don't want anything like that, just leave it empty. [Here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/share/examples/bitcoin.conf) you  can find more about the possibilities.

> And another question is right now I haven't closed the wallet in fear of losing the synchronization that it took so long, So the next time when I want to access the wallet I can directly start my start testnet.bat file??

That's ok to restart it. Assuming you start `bitcoind` or `bitcoin-qt` with the same data directory, it will continue with the progress from the last session.